# TCP Reliability testing

Tags: testing, tcp, reliability

I am working on a project where I need to test whether TCP reliability is in action or not.
For example I want to check something like this
1)I have a client which makes a request for a resource say using HTTP
2)Initially all the TCP 3 Way Hand shake would happen and a GET request would be placed.
3)The server would respond with appropriate response.

I am trying to tweak the contents from the Server side (I am taking care of the TCP stack).
In such a case I want to test if the server is sendign the packet reliably or not.
For eg:I want to simulate an environment where the Client doesnt ACK for the TCP Payload it recieeved hence forcing the server to resend the data after sometime.

Any tools to do test something like this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The server won't notice this at all, it's handled internally within the stack.

Comment: You can use tcpdump or Wireshark to see the retransmissions.

Comment: Hi The problem I am facing is the client immediately acks the receieved data(the TCP stack on client side) and thus the TCP stack on the server doesnt have a chance to retransmit the data.Is there any way I can test this ? Or do I assume the TCP stack would take care of this.We are kind of playing with the TCP streams so thought it was better to check this functionality

Comment: Unless you're writing your own TCP stack, you should just assume that the existing TCP stack will take care of this -- that's what everyone in the world does. If you are creating your own stack, google **tcp stack tester** and you'll find some utilities.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not creating my own TCP stack but I am inserting packets onto the stack by altering packets which I receive(Something like Deep Packet Inspection and altering the payload)

Comment: In that case, you might indeed want to make use of one of those tools, since you're effectively modifying the stack.